# How to use a number range as the x-axis on an excel bar chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have some data that I want to translate into a bar chart in Excel, however I am unsure on how to make it so my x-axis is in the correct format I need it in.

Here is the Excel data:

[image]

And here is how I want the end result to look:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this on Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you try it? Here's your data and the chart I made from it. The only difference is that I added a label above the Y values but not above the X values.

[image]

Even if you don't do the trick with the label above the Y values, this data produces the chart you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though that is what ought to result if you choose the bar graph. Assuming the first column is labels (text) and the second column is values (numeric).

You could bar graph the second column and then edit the result to name the first column as labels on the x axis.

I'd like to see what you are getting when you try to graph these columns.